TailwindCSS: Conditional class application not working as expected
I'm using TailwindCSS to style my web application, but I've encountered an issue with conditional classes. I want to apply different widths to my hero image based on the device orientation (portrait or landscape).
According to the TailwindCSS documentation, I should be able to use the @media directive in my CSS file to define these conditions. However, when I apply the classes landscape:w-80 and w-full conditionally, neither of them seem to be taking effect.
Here's an example of the code I'm using:
<img src="./assets/home/hero.png" alt="Hero" class="mx-auto w-full landscape:w-80 object-cover md:m-auto md:h-full lg:w-[32rem]" />

I've also defined the screens in my tailwind.config.js file as follows:
screens: {
  'portrait': { 'raw': '(orientation: portrait)' },
  'landscape': { 'raw': '(orientation: landscape)' },
},

Despite this configuration, the w-80 class scoped to portrait is not being applied when I switch to landscape or even if I try portrait scope. The image always takes up the full width of the screen.
Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong? Am I missing something fundamental about how conditional classes work in TailwindCSS?

For me it's working, could you add please a Minimal, Reproducible Example?
